# Generate multiple War from one project with Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have developed a WebApp (that i'll call W)used in conjunction with 3 different applications (A,B and C).

W needs different dependencies based on which application it is used in conjunction with(for example different versions of Oracle Coherence).

At the moment I use 3 maven projects with the exact same code (the code from W) with different configuration files and different dependencies.

I would like to be able to generate my 3 wars without having 3 times the very same code (the code from W) in 3 different projects.

Is it possible?Is it possible with maven? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try Maven profiles? It is possible you can do what you want with profiles.

Comment: well I thought about it(and I think it could work) but it looks like the "dirty way" of doing things (may be the only one though)

Comment: Yes, I do not know if Maven profiles was thought for doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these projects have anything in common, it makes most sense to have 4 war projects:

- one for the common part, with all the common classes and resources
- one for each deviation

Then you can use [WAR Overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) to embed the common part in each project.

IMHO this is better than trying to put all the dependencies into one pom, using profiles or other tricks.

BTW [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193385/building-different-maven-artifacts-for-different-containers) is very similar to yours.

Comment: well, my problem is : all my code (W) needs coherence dependency during the build; but each version of my application(A B C) require a different coherence version :s.
For example code for A needs coherence 3.5 (so I need coherence 3.5 dependency in the project)
code B need coherence 3.7 (so I need coherence 3.7 dependency in this project)
Code A and B are exactly the same.
My problem there, I think is that my common part classes cannot compile without the different dependencies...
not sure if I was clear enough :s

Comment: do you mean that you compile the same classes against different versions of the `coherence` library? If that is the case, you can select one of the versions in your common code in `provided` scope (so it don't get to WEB-INF/lib/), and have the concrete war projects each with the concrete version in `runtime` scope so it is added there

Comment: thanks for the answer. yes it is the case. I think I understand what you mean but I do not need a "concrete" version. Coherence is provided for the 3 versions. It is used during compilation, then it uses the jar on the server. (the more I explain the more I think it is complicated for nothing...if only we could just add provided dependencies without giving the version :s )

Comment: If you mark the dependency `provided` then you can select just _any_ version that is sufficient for compilation, isn't it? So I don't see any problem with this...

Comment: well, may be.Thought it would be kind of...dirty way...setting the dependency to one version and using yet another. thanks ^^

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a library project and set this as dependency to your web applications?

So you have one code base only (in the library) and the configuration is in the 3 war projects.